# nginx not forwarding request to php-fpm if allow/deny is used in location

Tags: php, nginx

I have the following nginx configuration to forward requests for PHP files to php-fpm:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    try_files      $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.socket;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $host;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;
}
```

Everything is working fine with that one. Recently we have encountered a lot of attempts to log in to our backend from strange IPs, assuming a brute force attack. Now we want to block the backend for everyone except our own IP, so I've added the following configuration:

```
location ~ /backend {
    allow [our-ip];
    deny all;
}
```

and it works good regarding the `deny` sending a 403 to anyone not having that IP, but when you request from the `allow`ed IP, nginx sends the index.php as a file to the client instead of forwarding the request to php-fpm and I can't figure out what to do. I even tried something like

```
location ~ /backend/.*?\.php {
    allow [our-ip];
    deny all;
}
```

and included the whole php-fpm configuration from the beginning of my question after the `deny`, but still no success. I'm totally out of ideas as to how I could get this to work and appreciate any help with that. Thank you very much.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752660/nginx-server-configuration-returns-php-code/42759189#42759189) for guidance, but you need a full `fastcgi` configuration inside any `location` that processes PHP URIs.

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick, thank you very much. I wasn't aware of that and thought nginx would fall back to the other `location` since it still matched the URI. Not sure if I should flag my question as duplicate since the question itself differs but the solution is the same?